# Wonder how codility.com test cases are defined?

Tags: php

I was giving codility.com a try. For the test "PermMissingElem" on https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/1

I wrote a PHP solution which is not very nice, but still works for all my test cases.

Codility only gives me 20% telling me about several test cases that failed. Here are some of them.

For example:
**empty_and_single**
 
empty list and single element   0.050 s.    RUNTIME ERROR 
tested program terminated unexpectedly
stdout:
Invalid result type, int expected.

**missing_first_or_last**
 
the first or the last element is missing    0.050 s.    RUNTIME ERROR 
tested program terminated unexpectedly
stdout:
Invalid result type, int expected.

**single**
 
single element  0.050 s.    RUNTIME ERROR 
tested program terminated unexpectedly
stdout:
Invalid result type, int expected.

I know this test has been solved here before I just wonder what exactly their tests mean and why my solution fails on them.

Here is my solution PHP code:

```
function solution($A) {
    $noe = count($A);
    if($noe == 0)
        return 1;
    for($i=1;$i<=$noe;$i++)
    {
        if(!in_array($i,$A,TRUE))
            return $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't return *any* result, when the last element is missing. For example with array [1] correct result is 2, but your function doesn't return anything.
Another example: with array [1, 2] your solution doesn't return anything, but should return 3.

I think you won't have any problems with fixing this bug. Although you will have performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is in C#, my program gave 100% correct and 100% performance.

```
Array.Sort(A);
if(A.Length == 0 )
{          
    return 1;                     
}      
else      
{  
    for(int i=0;i<A.Length;i++)   
    {    
        if(A[i] != i+1)    
        {
            return i+1;    
        }

    }
}

return A.Length + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my 100% php solution to PermMissingElem in codility, is very simple, just name your variables properly:

```
function solution($A) {
// write your code in PHP5.5
sort($A);
$index = 0;
foreach($A as $value)
{
    $expected = $index+1;
    if ($expected != $value) return $expected;
    $index++;
}
return $index+1;
```

}